# Get json value by json key if the key name is variable value

Tags: javascript

I have json string and want to get a value by key, but key name is value of some variable. To resolve the issue I've found this

```
window[varName]
```

and tried to use as following

```
<script>
var jsonStr = '{"someProperty":"Value of someProperty","somePropertyAndSuffix":"Value of somePropertyAndSuffix"}';
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

var propAsString = 'someProperty';

console.log(jsonObj.window[propAsString]);
console.log(jsonObj.window[propAsString]+'AndSuffix');
</script>
```

but I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'someProperty' of undefined

If I try

```
console.log(jsonObj[window[propAsString]]);
console.log(jsonObj[window[propAsString]+'AndSuffix']);
```

I get two `undefined`

Comment: Why do you have `window` in there?

Comment: First of all, window property is not defined in jsonObj.
2nd, you should do jsonObj[propAsString + 'AndSuffix']

Comment: If you know `jsonObj` and `propAsString` are defined, you can just do `jsonObj[propAsString]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `window` and it will work. `jsonObj` would be accessible on `window` (`window.jsonObj`) as javascript is [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) the assignments with var to the closest scope (in this case the window).

```js
var jsonStr = '{"someProperty":"Value of someProperty","somePropertyAndSuffix":"Value of somePropertyAndSuffix"}';
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

var propAsString = 'someProperty';

console.log(jsonObj[propAsString]);
console.log(jsonObj[propAsString + 'AndSuffix']);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I correctly understand this, but this is how to solve this:

```js
const jsonStr = '{"someProperty":"Value of someProperty","somePropertyAndSuffix":"Value of somePropertyAndSuffix"}'
const obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr)
const propAsString = 'someProperty'
console.log(obj[propAsString], obj[propAsString + 'AndSuffix'])
```